# CSS fixed menu title and buttons overlapping - mobile view

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, header, title

I'm having trouble with a button overlapping my header title in the mobile view (looks fine in computer view). I'm trying to find a way for the button and the header title to both fit in the header, possibly by resizing according to changing width? if that's possible.

Here is the CSS for my header:

```
    header: {
        background: '#C4C4C4',
        height: '100px',
        textAlign: 'center',
        boxShadow: '0px 2px 2px #A9A9A9',
        fontFamily: 'PT Sans Caption',
        fontSize: '36px',
        marginBottom: '20px',
        paddingTop: '20px',
        textTransform: 'uppercase',
        position: 'fixed',
        top: 0,
        width: '100%',
    },
    homeButton: {
        boxShadow: '0px 2px 2px #A9A9A9',
        fontFamily: 'PT Sans Caption',
        fontSize: '20px',
        display: 'block',
        position: 'absolute',
        marginLeft: '10px',
    },
```

Here is a screenshot of computer view:
[image]
Here is a screenshot of mobile view:
[image]

Basically I want the 'Add Movement' title to not be hidden by the home button. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: "position: absolute" remove the item from dom flow. So other elements are placed as if absolute items not there. You should remove that attribute. Then use media-query to set position absolute on bigger screen.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using Flexbox and a media query

```
header {
  display: flex;
  @media (max-width: [whatever you choose]px) {
     flex-wrap: wrap;
  }

}
```